# Generating random words in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, random, words

I wrote up a program that can sort words and determine any anagrams. I want to generate an array of random strings so that I can test my method's runtime.

```
public static String[] generateRandomWords(int numberOfWords){
String[] randomStrings = new String[numberOfWords];
Random random = Random();
    return null;
}
```

(method stub)

I just want lowercase words of length 1-10. I read something about generating random numbers, then casting to char or something, but I didn't totally understand. If someone can show me how to generate random words, then I should easily be able to just use a for loop to insert the words into the array. Thanks!

Comment: random words based on what source? (e.g. random numbers + ???? = random words)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Do you need actual English words, or just random strings that only contain letters a-z?

If you need actual English words, the only way to do it is to use a dictionary, and select words from it at random.

If you don't need English words, then something like this will do:

```
public static String[] generateRandomWords(int numberOfWords)
{
    String[] randomStrings = new String[numberOfWords];
    Random random = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++)
    {
        char[] word = new char[random.nextInt(8)+3]; // words of length 3 through 10. (1 and 2 letter words are boring.)
        for(int j = 0; j < word.length; j++)
        {
            word[j] = (char)('a' + random.nextInt(26));
        }
        randomStrings[i] = new String(word);
    }
    return randomStrings;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! One thing you need to to is cast 'a' to char or else the compiler freaks out at you. Thanks everyone!

Comment: No, you don't need to cast `'a'` to `char`, but the result of the addition (since this is automatically `int`). So it should be in fact `word[j] = (char)('a' + random.nextInt(26));`

Comment: Thanks for the correction, it's been a while since I worked with raw characters in Java.

Comment: Haha, no problem...it took like 10secs to fix.

Comment: Random letters aren't words

Answer (score 12):

[RandomStringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html) from commons-lang

Comment: New link up, no longer dead.

Answer (score 5):

Why generating random words? When you can use [some dictionaries](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/wordlist).

Comment: I am trying to get an average runtime, so randomly generated words should give me the best average. Also, this is for a school assignment, so I must conform to what my teacher wants...

Comment: you should have specified that, and tagged your question as "homework"

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't even know that was a category, but I suppose that would make perfect sense. I will be sure to do that next time.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to generate random words of a given length, you'll either need an algorithm to determine if a given string is a word (hard), or access to a word list of all the words in a given language (easy).  If it helps, [here's a list of every word in the Scrabble dictionary](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106l/cs106l.1102/assignments/dictionary.txt).

Once you have a list of all words in a language, you can load those words into an `ArrayList` or other linear structure.  You can then generate a random index into that list to get the random word.

Answer (score 2):

You can call this method for each word you want to generate. Note that the probability of generating anagrams should be relatively low though.

```
String generateRandomWord(int wordLength) {
    Random r = new Random(); // Intialize a Random Number Generator with SysTime as the seed
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(wordLength);
    for(int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++) { // For each letter in the word
        char tmp = 'a' + r.nextInt('z' - 'a'); // Generate a letter between a and z
        sb.append(tmp); // Add it to the String
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: +1 but I would suggest using `StringBuilder` instead of doing `out += ...`

Comment: @casablanca Wouldn't the compiler optimize his algorithm to use StringBuilder?

Comment: @Kin I'm pretty sure it wouldn't get optimized.

Comment: @Willi You are correct.  Since the String concat is in a loop, the compiler will not optimize the loop operations.  The compiler will try to optimize trivial String concats.  Source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java

Comment: @Kin U., @Willi: The compiler uses the StringBuilder, but he creates for each `+=` a new one. This line looks after compiling like this:
`out = new StringBuilder().append(out).append(r.nextInt('z'-'a')+'a').toString();`  – By the way, you should here convert to char again, since int + char = int, and thus your loop will append decimal numbers to the StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

If you want random words without using a dictionary...

1. Make a list of all the letters you want possible in your words
2. Generate a random index to pick out a letter from the list
3. Repeat until you have your desired word length

Repeat these steps for the number of words you want to generate.